# Install a custom file generated during compilation in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'd like to install a custom file which is generated during compilation of a CMake project:

In my project the file `SampleDictionary_rdict.pcm` is generated by a command from an external module during compilation, and I would like to have it copied to `$CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/lib` with `make install`

The issue I'm running into is all the variants of `install(...)` I've tried require the file to exist *before* compilation.

The command from an external module that generates the file is:

```
ROOT_GENERATE_DICTIONARY(
    SampleDictionary
    ...
    )
```

This generates `SampleDictionary_rdict.pcm` in my build directory.

For example, if I try to add:

```
install(TARGETS SampleDictionary DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
```

to the end of my `CMakeLists.txt` I have the issue of the file not existing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`install(TARGETS ...` is used to install targets built within the project. You want to install the file `SampleDictionary_rdict.pcm` so you need a [variant](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/install.html?highlight=install#installing-files) for files: `install(FILES ...`

Comment: Perfect: `install(FILES build/SampleDictionary_rdict.pcm DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)` did the trick. (where `build` is my CMake build directory)

Comment: @ddavis Yeah but... that only works if your build directory is `build`. This isn't a good solution for that problem. Use `install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SampleDictionary_rdict.pcm DESTINATION lib)` instead.